# How to run task in another terminal with vscode integrated terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

My problem is default integrated terminal in [vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com) is different with tasks.json that needed.

so when I want to run command in tasks.json I having many trouble.

for example if you set default integrated terminal to [wsl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about), and you want to run [bat file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file) in tasks.json like below, you got a some error and task does not working.

```
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "build",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "build.bat",
        "args": [],
        "presentation": {
            "echo": true,
            "reveal": "always",
            "focus": true,
            "panel": "shared",
            "showReuseMessage": true,
            "clear": false
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in [vscode documents for tasks](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks), one section is about [common questions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_common-questions) that say something like below

> Can a task use a different shell than the one specified for the Integrated Terminal?

and answer this question is yes with below details

> You can override a task's shell with the options.shell property. You can set this per task, globally, or per platform. For example, to use cmd.exe on Windows, your tasks.json would include:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "windows": {
        "options": {
            "shell": {
                "executable": "cmd.exe",
                "args": [
                    "/d", "/c"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    ...
```